# multiboot usb recognized by bios but won't boot

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot, bootable-media

I'm really starting to accumulate alot of usb drives, so I decided to try and make a multi boot usb drive and I can't seem to get it to boot. I have tried using two different multiboot usb creator programs and they both have the same result (YUMI and multibootusb) -- They will show up in the boot order menu, and they seem to work when I run them in QEMU (a tool that comes with multiboot usb to test boot a newly created usb)

I have been searching google for hours but all I haven't found any relevant solution to my problem. A few people said using a different usb worked, but I have tried that already....does a usb drive have to have certain specs to be used as a multi boot drive?

Answer (score 0):

If it boots via QEMU but not from your BIOS, then your BIOS is not booting it in the correct way. Have you enabled CSM\Legacy booting and disabled fast boot and Secure Boot in the BIOS boot options.
Also, some BIOSes need to see two partitions on a USB drive in order to boot from it correctly. Try using a partition tool (e.g. EaseUS Home Partition Master or gparted) and create a small Primary 2nd partition (of any size and type).
If you create an Easy2Boot USB drive, this will be done for you automatically.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I should have included that in my post. I tried putting legacy mode to enabled mode and auto mode, secure boot has always been off since I started using linux, also disabled fast boot too. Will easy2boot make a multi usb? I will also try adding a second partition, thanks.